# I can't render CalendarView in Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Stackoverflow community!

I have one problem with rendering Android native control in Xamarin.Forms…(CalendarView)
Help me please!

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WinSoft_Planner.Controls;
using WinSoft_Planner.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WinSoft_Planner.Controls.CalendarViewControl), typeof(CalendarRendererDroid))]
namespace WinSoft_Planner.Droid
{
    public class CalendarRendererDroid : ViewRenderer<WinSoft_Planner.Controls.CalendarViewControl, CalendarView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CalendarViewControl> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(Forms.Context);
            calendarView.Date = Date.Parse(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());

            SetNativeControl(calendarView);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!
Best wishes!

Comment: you have not described the specific problem you are having, or asked an actual question

Comment: Could you clearly describe the problem you are encountering?I test the codes above,and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem with using Calendar plugin for Xamarin Forms.